# My calculated column seems to be ignoring the values of the measures I'm using

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm not an expert in Power BI, and started about a year ago using DAX.

I have two measures calculated as the following>

`SelectedWeekStart = SELECTEDVALUE(StatsbyWeek[StartWeek])`
`SelectedEndWeek = [SelectedWeekStart] + 4`

And I have a table that I want to create an additional column `IsSelectedWeek`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFx5Q.png)

To create this column, I'm using:

`IsWeekSelected = IF(allocation_dim[Date] >= SelectedWeekStart && allocation_dim[Date] <= SelectedEndWeek, 1, 0)`

However, I might be doing something wrong, because the column is entirely filled with zeros, as if the measures had any values at all.

Could you give some light on it?

Comment: Calculated Columns are calculated at dataset refresh time and are static after that. They are not recalculated at runtime.

Comment: Hey Sam, thanks for your quick response.